# How to wrap content around an image with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to wrap content around an image with CSS? Div with class `.header` should be wrap border by the width of text inside it. Div with class `.body` should be in new line after `.header` div.

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZHzX.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="header">
            Here is header bar
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    float: left;
}
.header {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56L9yo52/

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:table-cell`

```
.image {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:top;
padding-right:5px;
}
.header {
border: 1px solid #000;
margin-bottom: 20px;
display:inline; 
}
.text{display: table-cell; vertical-align:top;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/56L9yo52/4/)

Comment: Thanks. But I need to wrap content around image. Please, see my picture.

Comment: Thanks again. But div with class .header should be wrap border by the width of text inside it. (sorry, maybe it bad explanation)

Answer (score 0):

Use padding for image

```
.image { padding-right:10px; }
```